# Where to find Video Indexer code samples in TypeScript or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, azure, azure-functions, azure-video-indexer

I am currently testing out the Microsoft Video Indexer but I can't find any resources how to connect using JavaScript or TypeScript. You guys have any sources?

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/hxlnt/video-indexer/blob/master/example/app.js) meet your requirement ?

Comment: i have tried that just to make sure. is this right?

`
import vindexer from 'video-indexer';

const Vindexer = new vindexer(apiKey);

Vindexer.getAccounts().then(function(result) {
    console.log(result.body);
  });
`

i am using a node framework

Answer (score 0):

```
 <iframe width="100%" height="400" 
            [src]="aiVideoUrl" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

In iFrame you can pass the URL it Will play the video in iFrame